# Put webview URL in adress bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I need to get a URL from UIWebView and put it in the address bar. I used this code, but it doesn't work at all.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    [webAdress2 setText:[URL absoluteString]];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Your code seems OK to me, error must be elsewhere.

Comment: You need to provide more info on webAdress2, what is it, where do you create it etc

Comment: I am set up webAdress2 and webView2 like this -     NSString *settingValue2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url2"];
    NSURL *urlx2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue2]];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx2];
    [webView2 loadRequest:request2];
    [webAdress2 setText:settingValue2];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem today. Apparently the [request URL] only gets value after the webView has finished loading. So I made a property in the controller with a webView so that I could set a value for it from the class which calls that controller and then just used something like:

```
[webAdress2 setText:self.theURL];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: basically before calling the ViewController with UIWebView in it, call a method like
    someViewController.theURL = theURLYouNeed;
It will make theURL of that viewController be same as theURLYouNeed.